# UIDatePicker not updating UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I've been using a multitide of tutorials and `stackoverflow` answers to piece this together. I have a `UITextField` which when the user taps slides up a `UIDatePicker` (instead of keyboard). Once the datepicker is closed the `TextField` should update with the selected date.

However it just has the current date/time in there no matter what you change it to. What am I missing? I want it formatted as **MM / dd / yyyy** too.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

//birthday view
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
UIToolbar *doneBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 44)];

datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
_birthdayField.inputView = datePicker;
[_birthdayField setInputAccessoryView:doneBar];


[doneBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                           target:nil
                           action:nil];
[doneBar setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                      initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                      target:self
                                                      action:@selector(datePickerDone:)],nil ] animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)datePickerDone:(id)sender {
    [_birthdayField resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender {
    if([_birthdayField isFirstResponder]) {
        UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)_birthdayField.inputView;
        _birthdayField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", picker.date];
    }
}
```

I assume it's something I'm missing in updateTextField.

Answer (score 0):

Because you resign the _birthdayField when the done button is touched.

So the code in updateTextfield if block never gets called.

Comment: How do I stop it from doing that? Removing the if block made no difference

Answer (score 0):

After playing around I figured out the issue. Bseh's answer didn't apply as when I placed a breakpoint in updateTextField it was definitely hitting it. I changed the following:

```
- (void)updateTextField:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *datePickerFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [datePickerFormat setDateFormat:@"MM  /  dd  /  yyyy"]; //here specify your format..
    NSString *dateString = [datePickerFormat stringFromDate:sender.date];
    self.birthdayField.text = dateString;
}
```

Changing that `id` to `UIDatePicker` made the difference for me! I've also added the formatting I wanted.